# How to show users email address in notification emails?

Tags: email

We've recently re-installed our Sharepoint 2007 server, and migrated the old content.

Previously if a user edited a calendar, the notification email sent out would appear as though it's from the editing user. For example:

> Joe Bloggs makes a new calendar appointment. A notification email is
>   sent out, appearing as though the email is from joe.bloggs@website.com

This is no longer happening on our new system.

In the "Outgoing E-Mail Settings" of our Sharepoint system, the "From address:" field is blank at the moment. We use Exchange as our email server.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

You should just need to specify an email address in that outgoing email address and emails generated by SharePoint will come from that user.

Comment: That field only allows you to specify a single email address. We would like it to show the email address of whichever user made the edit.